# Excel file to count total rows in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA macro to count the number of rows in `sheet2` of Excel file

```
Dim cnt As Integer 
Dim i As Integer

cnt = Range("Sheet2").Rows.Count ' giving error at this row
For i = 2 To cnt
    t1 = "A" + CStr(i)
    t2 = "B" + CStr(i)
Next i
```

But it giving error:

> Method 'Range' of object '_global' failed

Comment: i get this error ( Method 'Range' of object '_global' failed

Answer (score 5):

`Range` is used for *Cell Range* not for **Excel Sheets**.

Try the followings:

1. To get the **count of used rows**:

   ```
   cnt = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
   ```
2. To get the **count of all rows of the sheet**:

   ```
   cnt = Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count
   ```
3. To get the **count of rows of a specific `Range`**:

   ```
   cnt = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A6500").Rows.Count
   ```

I think you are looking for used cell range. Define variables as Long to resolve the overflow issue

```
Dim cnt As Long 
Dim i As Long
```

Comment: Just a quick note, your 3rd option is not very useful because if they're hardcoding the range (1:6500) then they'd already know there are 6500 rows. Another useful way to get the number of rows is `cnt = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`. This will get the  used range up to the first blank row.

Comment: I have just provided an example, please don't stick with the values. you can use any excel range and get the row count.

Answer (score 1):

Sheet2 is a sheet, not a range.

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following code:

```
Dim crb1 As Long


'Count Rows

    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    crb1 = ActiveCell.Row

    MsgBox ("Number of rows are ") & Str(crb1)
```